# What is the intuition of FFT for polynomial multiplication?

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

What is the intuition of FFT for polynomial?
Multiplications on two ($N-1$)-degree polynomial is naively done in $O(N^2)$. Using FFT, we can reduce the complexity to $O(N\log N)$.
As for addition, w/ or w/o FFT, the complexity is $O(N)$ in both cases.

I know this fact. But I do not understand the intuition.

Why does this hold?

Comment: See section 2.6 in this text: http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf

Comment: Multiplication of polynomial behaves as convolution of their coefficients. And convolution becomes multiplication in the Fourier domain according to the convolution theorem.